# .htaccess redirect to certain folder with different url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this architecture :

```
- api
- apps
- public
```

Actually i have this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
  RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This .htaccess redirect to the /public folder automatically. But now I created a API folder and I want to redirect to the API folder if the url is /api.

When I'm calling http://my-domain.com/api I want to go to the api folder and for all other URL I want to redirect to the public folder.

Could you help me ? I'm totally bad in this .htaccess configuration.

Comment: Start reading the documentation for the tools you use. There is a `RewriteCond` command for that: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the folder from your rule, try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
  RewriteRule ^((?!api).*)$ public/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this still redirect to the public folder :/

Comment: Shouldn't there be a slash in there somewhere anyhow?  What if the url is example.com/apiaries/whatever-goes-next

Comment: hum, your edit works well but my web services are not found if I'm calling mydomain.com/api/robots I got a 404. I think the problem is in my routes configuration php side. Thanks.